# How to navigate in a view result from node full view

Tags: views

I have a view which displays a list of nodes. When I click a node link from the view to see node's full view, I want in this node full view to add "back to list", "previous" and "next" links to let user navigate in view results.

I think to add view name and exposed filters selected values as parameters to node links in  the view, so I can compute navigation links in node full view. First question : isn't it an easier, cleaner, or more drupal compliant way to achieve this ?

If not : is there a better way to modify the links that in node teaser tlp.php ? I guess I could use hook_node_view_alter (I'm D7), but wouldn't it cause potential performance issue (I mean it need to test if I'm in my particular view for every node everywhere in the site, though it's a very specific feature)

Thanks for your help,

Philip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Views Navigation](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_navigation) module. This seems to be a good fit for your requirement.

> This module adds next and previous links on content pages when
>   accessed from a view. It is intended for dynamic and/or paged view
>   results, where the result set changes according to exposed filters,
>   current user access rights,...

Also here is the [link](https://www.drupal.org/node/1276920) to the comparison other node based navigation modules.